# Error while installing selenium webdriver on ubuntu, using python3, chrome

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I am at the stage of installing Selenium on Ubuntu using Python3 (I want to automate Chrome).

I have installed pip3, chromedriver and when I run the following code in Pycharm:

```
import os  
from selenium import webdriver  
chromedriver = '/home/anastasia/development/python/projects/selenium/chromedriver'  
os.environ['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = chromedriver  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)  
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Get an error "ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'" then I press alt+Enter on webdriver - select Install package and get an error:

> "Install Packages Failed.   pip install webdriver   Non-zero exit code
>   (1)"

I assume the problem is with the version of pip used. How should I correctly set the version pip3 to be used?

Comment: What is the result of "pip --version"?

Comment: try install using pip3 install webdriver

Comment: @JeroenHeier :~$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/anastasia/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
:~$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/anastasia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

Comment: @zhiqianghuang Tried "pip3 install webdriver" it says:
Collecting webdriver
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for webdriver

Comment: pip3 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in google-chrome version. It appeared I got not the lattest. And it was incompatible with the latest chromedriver. After I upgraded chrome all worked successfully!